# how to let user draw a line on canvas on x axis only with background image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a canvas that contain image,i want to let user to draw line over it ,on x axis only,and with out clearing the background image.

```js
var lala = document.getElementById('demo');
var canvas = lala,
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  img = new Image;
img.onload = start;
img.src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/300';

function start() {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, demo.width, demo.height);
}

function drawOnX() {

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="demo" width=300 height=300></canvas>
<button onclick = "drawOnX();"> start drawing </button>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/lineTo

Comment: i edited my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [`moveTo(x, y)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/moveTo) and [`lineTo(x, y)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/lineTo) to define the path then use [`stroke()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/stroke) to draw it, you can use [`lineWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/lineWidth) and [`strokeStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/strokeStyle) to specify the thickness and the style of the line, respectively.

```js
var lala = document.getElementById('demo');
var canvas = lala,
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  img = new Image;
img.onload = start;
img.src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/300';

function start() {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, demo.width, demo.height);
}

function drawOnX() {
  ctx.moveTo(0, 150);
  ctx.lineTo(300, 150);

  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "red";

  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="demo" width=300 height=300></canvas>
<button onclick = "drawOnX();"> start drawing </button>
```

You can make as many calls to `moveTo` and `lineTo` to draw complicated paths or shapes (for example a star) before you call `stroke`.

---

Alternatively, if you're only interested in horizontal lines, you can use [`fillRect(x, y, width, height)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillRect) to draw long tiny rectangles to mimic a line (the width will be the full width of the canvas and the height will be the thickness of the line), you can use [`fillStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillStyle) in this case to style the rectangle, like so:

```js
var lala = document.getElementById('demo');
var canvas = lala,
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  img = new Image;
img.onload = start;
img.src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/300';

function start() {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, demo.width, demo.height);
}

function drawOnX() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";

  ctx.fillRect(0, 149, 300, 2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="demo" width=300 height=300></canvas>
<button onclick = "drawOnX();"> start drawing </button>
```

Comment: thanks,but in this case the user isn't drawing he only press a button.I want to let him draw.

Comment: @adelkanso http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/